# Visual Studio speech recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm trying to built a speech recognition system using visual studio c# and built in system.speech. I was trying to build it for my native language but i can't do it. My question is, have you ever tried using this tool for other language than English if yes, did it work ? Thanks in advance

SpeechRecognitionEngine recSpeech = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-PL"));

Comment: if you are on Windows 7, you need [Microsoft Speech Platform SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226). Your language is available.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 and I have installed a language pack but yet it still doesn't work :<

Comment: _doesn't work_ is not a meaningful information. Make sure you have installed the Speech Recognition language package (not the UI Language Package, different story). Take a look at [Project Oxford](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedcsharpdesktop), and [The Bing Speech Recognition Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx). You may also use the Speech Platform SDK already mentioned. In this case, you need to get familiar with [Speech Recognition Grammar Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/)